# Return to MainForm if a condition is not set

Tags: vb.net, forms, devexpress, controls

I am writing a program in DevExpress and I have stumbled upon a problem. I want one tile to show if a condition is set, in this case input a specific value. If the user inputs it they will go to the window they want to go. Otherwise it will have to go back to the main form.

The problem I am experiencing is getting the program to go to the main form if the condition is not set. Whenever it tries to do that the program crashes.

Can you please help me? Thanks!

```
Private Sub windowsUIView1_QueryControl(sender As Object, e As QueryControlEventArgs) Handles windowsUIView1.QueryControl
    ....
    ElseIf e.Document Is Document9 Then
        Dim cuentaInicial = InputBox("Por favor introduzca la cuenta inicial del día", "Inicial")

        If cuentaInicial = "" Then
            MsgBox("Por favor introduzca un valor inicial", vbCritical, "Error")
            Me.Refresh()' <-- Problem here
            Exit Sub
        End If

        Try
            Dim inicial As Double = Double.Parse(cuentaInicial)
            e.Control = New Caja
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(cuentaInicial & ": No es el formato correcto. Favor de verificar", vbCritical, "Error")
            Me.Refresh() '<-- problem here
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you wish to show a dialog on clicking a tile. If so, I suggest that you create handle the [WindowsUIView.TileClick](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraBarsDocking2010ViewsWindowsUIWindowsUIView_TileClicktopic) event instead of WindowsUIView.QueryControl event(raised when the document is already shown).

Within the WindowsUIView.TileClick event handler you can check whether or no you can navigate into the corresponding document via setting the Handled property at event arguments level:

```
Sub WindowsUIView1_TileClick(sender As Object, e As DevExpress.XtraBars.Docking2010.Views.WindowsUI.TileClickEventArgs) Handles WindowsUIView1.TileClick
    ...
    If e.Document Is Document9 Then
        Dim cuentaInicial = InputBox("Por favor introduzca la cuenta inicial del día", "Inicial")
        If cuentaInicial = "" Then
            MsgBox("Por favor introduzca un valor inicial", vbCritical, "Error")
            e.Handled = True ' !!!do not naviate into the document
            Exit Sub
        End If
    ...
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was intending to do and it worked like a charm. Thanks!